# What does “Anyone who is married” mean in “Anyone who is married should know that facts and logic are not always helpful to one’s cause”?

Tags: meaning, idioms, word-usage

I’m drawn to the phrase, “anyone who is married” taken from Benn Steil's recently published book, *The Battle of Bretton Woods* that deals with the battle engaged by Maynard Keynes and Harry White, each championing British and U.S. governments’ financial platforms in Bretton Woods 70 years ago.

> “What was Keyne’s substantive role in the creation of the Lend-Lease
>   Agreement? It is hard to imagine that anyone could have better
>   identified and articulated the huge risks that Morgenthau, White,
>   Hull, and Welles’s demands posed for Britain’s postwar solvency. But
>   **anyone who is married**, as Keynes was, should know that facts and logic
>   are not always helpful to one’s cause. - page 123.

What does “anyone who is married (should know something)” mean? 
To me, being married or unmarried has nothing to do with having judgement, intelligence or wisdom.  Why then should it be followed by the words “as Keynes was,” when it’s nothing special to readers?

Is it a figurative expression for any worldly, sensible person? Is anyone who is unmarried unworldly and insensible? As Japanese people, we have no notion similar to this. Indeed there are many wise men and women who are single. I don't understand the  phrase even it is a joke. Is this a usual phrasal expression, one that is politically incorrect?

Comment: As I am married and my wife has an active account here, I will refrain from discussing the merits of Steil's observations.

Comment: The phrase *as Keynes was* doesn't come out of nowhere. Keynes is married. As a married man, he should know that facts and logic are not always helpful to one's cause. No mystery at all language-wise (though the supposition works for both spouses, not just men). It is hard to imagine that you understood the first two-thirds of that excerpt and not the last.

Comment: @medica I would dispute the "it is hard to imagine that..." part of your comment, as the asker is from Japan and they may not have that meme there.  In general, it is a good idea to remember that people asking questions about English may be from different cultures, and we should assume the question is an honest one unless substantial proof to the contrary is in evidence.

Comment: @msouth - it is not a "meme" any more than *conflict* is a "meme". It is inherent in close relationships. It is not an idiom. It is not a metaphor. It is plain English. If one can understand the first parts, one should have no difficulty with the rest. And finally, I know where the OP resides. I also know he's married, so might understand the author's comparison. At the risk of sounding ironic, you *presume* much.

Comment: @medica. I know you are an esteemed physician, and you know there is no difference of inteligence level - commprehension of, and ability of solving the preblem between the married and unmarried. I don't feel it relevant even if it is a bad joke. Beside I don't understand why the question which earned 7 upvotes (2 downvotes), 800 + views, 6 answers, 1 favorite question, and 24 comments including 21 'useful' score marking one which is well above an average score of my own 850 questions was put on hold as off-topic, while so many users are interested in, enjoying, and responsive to the question.

Comment: Personally I don't get the off-topic votes.  The OP correctly presumed the literal interpretation of the words so it's not like he's asking for someone to look it up in a dictionary.  It may seem obvious to a native speaker, but perhaps the married joke/idiom is something that doesn't cross cultures very well, and it seems like something that would be difficult to Google for.  Seems like a legitimate question to me.  I have voted to reopen.

Comment: @YoichiOishi - I assure you, alluding to your marital status was not a joke of any kind. I am sincerely sorry to have offended you. I mentioned it because, as a married person (to which group I also belong), you may have insight into the author's statement, that's the whole of it. No one ever seems to think *their* question should be closed. Perhaps you might ask in meta, as that is where such a defense belongs. Granted your question, although simply about plain English, was more interesting than a lot of questions here recently, there was nothing mysterious about it.

Comment: @YoichiOishi - I see you have changed your question to one of a more cultural and philosophical, not language, nature. Humans have different cultures, but even within different cultures, humans are far more alike than they are different. The comment is not disparaging of one's mate (male or female) but rather points out that emotion and bias at times overriding reason is inherent to humanity. Regardless of culture or "political correctness", I am quite certain that everyone feels this way sometimes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The meaning is literal here. *Anyone who is married* just means "any person who is married".

The implication is probably that in marital disputes, or generally in the life of a married couple, the fact that one of the parties operates based on facts and in a logical way is at best orthogonal (if not harmful) to the outcome of the dispute, or the general balance, for that party; it might take quite different skills than logical, factual reasoning to win a marital dispute or to be generally contented in one's marriage. It is implied that such an experience, which might be counter-intuitive, can be gained in marriage. "Should know" means "can be expected to know/to have learned".

As such, the statement is strongly biased to say the very least. It is presumably a joke, harping on what the author expects to be a shared meme or feeling (about marriage).

Answer (score 10):

Benn Steil appears to be making a comparison between the inadequacy of mere logic and facts for deciding outcomes in one sphere of human relations (marriage), and the parallel inadequacy of logic and facts in another sphere of human relations/activity (economics and politics).

Keynes, Steil notes, was (or ought to have been) particularly familiar with the limitations of logic and facts in these areas, because he was both a married man and an economist.

So Steil is making both a general point about what he believes all married people know, and a particular (mildly humorous) point about what J M Keynes could be expected to know.

Answer (score 7):

Simply put.

As any "logical" married person (i.e. a man) will tell you, it's difficult to settle disputes (i.e causes) using facts and logic with a person who  does not (i.e. a woman). It's quite a sexist comment.

---

There is no dispute as to the meaning of the following

> [*as anyone who is married*...](https://www.google.it/search?q=until%20you%20have%20a%20child&oq=until%20you%20have%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.11337j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22as%20anyone%20who%20is%20married%22)
>
> [*as any married person*...](https://www.google.it/search?q=until%20you%20have%20a%20child&oq=until%20you%20have%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.11337j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22as%20any%20married%20person%22)

it refers to any husband or any wife.

What's interesting to note, if you click on the above Google links, are the verbs and fixed expressions that are used in conjunction: ***knows***, ***understands***, ***can testify*** and ***will tell you***. These are phrases usually directed at unmarried people who cannot relate, or are incapable of appreciating the problems and difficulties which typically occur in marriages. "As any married person knows" can be a presumptuous, somewhat arrogant statement, one which may infuriate many intelligent single people, but nevertheless it is an ingrained premise, one that is familiar to most.  Think of it as being similar to the cliché: *[Until you have a child of your own, you don't understand](https://www.google.it/search?q=until%20you%20have%20a%20child&oq=until%20you%20have%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.11337j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22until%20you%20have%20a%20child%22%20you%20do%20not%20understand)... etc.*

> *anyone who is married should know* (i.e. learned this to be true)

Now up to this point, I would argue fiercely that this refers to any man or woman who is in a marriage, it is *what* follows that premise that narrows the choice.

> But anyone who is married should know that **facts and logic** are not always helpful to one’s cause.

I am nearly fifty years old (I never thought I'd pull out the age card) and I cannot tell you the number of times I've heard and read that women are emotional, sensitive, instinctive and impulsive creatures who have great empathy, whilst men are better at map reading, can park cars better, are more into the sciences, and their brains are larger— actually that last bit *is* true.

There is a world famous book called *Men Are from Mars, Women Are from Venus* which in my view has perpetuated these stereotypical beliefs. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Are_from_Mars,_Women_Are_from_Venus) provides this little nugget (emphasis mine):

> One example is **men's complaint that if they offer solutions** to
>   problems that women bring up in conversation, the **women are not
>   necessarily interested** in solving those problems, but want mainly to
>   talk about them.

I hope, I have now explained the rationale and experience behind my original answer.

Comment: I wonder if in Japan this common male chauvinist  belief has ever taken root!!

Comment: @Josh61 Exactly. This is how I read the OP's question; there's apparently a cultural gap in this respect. In that case, it is quite a good question, and I cannot understand the downvotes.

Comment: +1 for specifying the unspoken (erm, unwritten) but most certainly real assumption that “facts and logic” is intended to apply to the _man_ in a marriage, not the woman. Also implicitly referenced is the meme that the wife always wins any marital dispute precisely because her way of arguing dismisses fact and logic entirely and instead defeats the poor husband with incomprehensible ambushes that take him quite unawares. A lot of unspoken cultural assumptions in so little a phrase, really.

Comment: While this interpretation is certainly possible, it is far from clear that the author's implication is what you presume it is. The phrase **anyone who is married** applies equally to persons of either sex: one does not have to be female to dismiss or misuse facts and logic, nor does one have to be male to apply them. In my opionion you, anemone, Josh61 and JBJacquet can all yourselves be regarded as sexist for having leapt to the conclusion that you have. -1

Comment: @ErikKowal - the author says "as Keynes was" (implying  that the counterpart is his wife , a woman..to whom the concept (prejudice)  of facts and logic is automatically applied).  BTW..no sexist here!!!!

Comment: @ErikKowal please read oerkelens's comment posted beneath Yoichi's question: **As I am married and my wife has an active account here, I will refrain from discussing the merits of Steil's observations.**. A comment written by a married man. I can laugh at myself, and I don't take offence, many a time my partner has accused me of being a "woman", i.e. of not using "logic". It's a common preconception held by many men (not all) in the western world and non. In my answer I paraphrased two answers which I thought were unnecessarily long-winded, and politically correct.

Comment: @ErikKowal I'm not leaping to the conclusion. I'm being pushed to it. It's just that without the biased optic, it's so terribly difficult to give any meaning to that sentence (what the deuce has marriage got to do with it?) Also, as Josh61 points out, there's no getting away from the fact that both Keynes and the author are men; this provides a context for the remark, and any discussion of whether it is valid for both sexes seems a bit academic.

Comment: @ErikKowal some can laugh at themselves without worrying about political correctness. The meaning behind the quote is clear, it's said by a married man tongue-in-cheek, it's a clichè, and one that I am all too familiar with.

Comment: While I suspect @Mari-LouA's interpretation is correct, you could also read it along the lines of "anyone (of either gender) who has been involved in a marital disagreement will know that facts and logic aren't always helpful".  It does after all say any*one* and not any *man*, and was only recently published.

Comment: I don't see why you would use oerkelens' comment to support your theory, unless you just assume he's sexist because he's a man.  An unbiased view of his comment would note that one half of a married couple is refraining from commenting due to the offense the other half might take, and made no implications that the other spouse might not make the same argument.  You've done more to present evidence of your own bias here than you have to support your original contention.

Comment: My comments which suggested that users either upvote the answers they preferred or write a better answer themselves, have been deleted. Other "chatty" and "obsolete" comments have been deleted as well, so fair dues. But I still don't see the point of people paraphrasing the same criticism repeatedly.

Comment: I don't understand why people are taking such offense at Mari's calling this quote sexist. Mostly because it obviously is sexist. The speaker was male and speaking to a male audience of a certain generation (well-established American/English professionals during WWII) and cultural prejudices of the time were that their wives did not argue using "facts and logic". Of course, the statement _could_ be intended non-gendered, but it wasn't. @ErikKowal, recognizing sexism, as Josh61 and JBJ did, isn't the same as being sexist.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this a usual phrasal, not politically correct?

"Anyone who is married" is not a stock phrase or idiom, but I very much doubt this author was the first ever to use it. It's a joke, that married life inevitably produces examples of irrationality.

Really what the author intends to insinuate here, I think, is that actually *everyone* knows, and Keynes should have taken into consideration, that not all arguments can be won by facts and logic. I don't believe there's any insult here to unmarried people, implying they wouldn't know the same thing. It's merely a facetious remark that married people certainly should know better than to think otherwise.

The question then is, why use marriage in particular as an example of something that would inevitably lead to irrational arguments? Why is that funny? The answer lies in how we expect people to feel about marriage. Does it strike home to the reader as particularly prone to irrational arguments, and if so why?

It's inevitable that some readers will interpret this in light of the dated and most certainly politically-incorrect cliché that husbands are factual and logical creatures who suffer at the hands of the irrationality of women. As such the remark does wander into politically-incorrect territory.

However, I don't believe we have enough here to condemn the author as a bigot, or even to conclude that he's intentionally appealing to that trope. After all, it is literally true that any close relationship (and marriage is widely held to be the closest whether it actually is or not), will more or less inevitably generate some irrational behaviour from both parties *eventually*, and both parties will find that from time to time their facts and logic come to nothing. If this is the intention then he could just as well have said, "anyone who has lived with another person, as Keynes did with his wife, should know..."

But that wouldn't be as funny. Why? Because it's wordier, for sure. Also because it doesn't play so directly into the readers' ideas of marriage. Some of those ideas are that it's universally chaotic and not always subject to logic. Some of those ideas are sexist. It really depends on the reader, and we cannot know what reader the author had in mind.

Comment: A good answer (+1). But one point occurs to me: if, instead of "But anyone who is married, as Keynes was, should know that facts and logic are not always helpful to one’s cause", Steil had written "But anyone who is a parent, as Keynes was, should know that facts and logic are not always helpful to one’s cause", would we be arguing about whether he was playing on a blanket stereotype about children, or would we simply assume that he had drawn attention to a universal truth about human relationships in general? (Let's assume that Keynes actually did have children, though in reality he did not.)

Comment: @ErikKowal - Exactly that. I see it not as disparaging of one's mate (male or female) but rather that emotion and bias at times overriding reason are inherent to humanity.

Comment: @ErikKowal: well, children too young to understand spoken language are, in point of fact, impervious to logic. So that version would allude to a fact, not just a stereotype (but perhaps also a stereotype of children and teenagers). It would arguably be more offensive to whoever it is Keynes was presenting his case to, though (Churchill?), to liken them not merely to a spouse but to a child. As far as rhetoric is concerned, I think using children to illustrate universal truths about human relationships is weaker than using adults.

Comment: @medica: that's the meaning in the context of the historical analysis, of course. However, the joke chooses to uses spouses as the illustrating example, which is at least somewhat critical of spouses. You wouldn't say, "anyone who has ever had a mathematics tutor, as Keynes did at Cambridge, should know that facts and logic are not always helpful to one's cause". The joke wouldn't work. The point is *at least* that married life in particular among human relationships is well understood to be frustrating to logic, even if no comment is intended on gender.

Answer (score 1):

Its about experience. Its possible to posses quite a bit of judgement, intelligence and wisdom yet still believe something foolish because one has not had the correct personal experience to show one the folly of said believe. For example if you grew up in the Southern USA and were raised to call people Sir and Mam then you might not now that many people hate being referred to in that way because it makes them feel old.

Believing that facts and logic alone are enough to persuade people is a mistaken belief that many people hold because they have not yet had a life experience that forces them to see ridiculousness of that stance. Marriage is such an experience.